# WALs increase for some reason

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, write-ahead-logging, postgresql-fdw

This is new to me. I have been searching the net but no result.

I have a server, **Server A**, that has been running for a few weeks, it is a new server. I set up FDW for this server to access all tables from a `public` schema from 2 databases (**db B1 and db B2**), lets call it **Server B**. All tables are "stored" on particular schema on server A on 3 different databases (db A1, A2, A3). **There is also `streaming replication` between this server and Server C**

Here is the summary of FDW that I do :

- Set up the **Server B** : add entry on `pg_hba` to accept all connection, `create user fdwuser` , reload the config file
- Set up the **Server A** :

1. Create these schemas on **db A1, A2, A3** to hold the data from **Server B** :

   ```
    CREATE SCHEMA reference;
    CREATE SCHEMA profile;
    GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA profile TO jhon, bon;
    GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA reference TO jhon, bon;
   ```
2. Create FDW extension for each databases on db A1, A2, A3:

   ```
   CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw;
   ```
3. Create foreign servers:

   ```
   CREATE SERVER foreign_profile 
     FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host '10.10.8.40', port '5432', dbname 'db_profile'); ` 

   CREATE SERVER foreign_referensi 
     FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host     '10.10.8.40', port '5432', dbname 'db_reference');`
   ```
4. Create user mapping:

   ```
   CREATE USER MAPPING FOR jhon SERVER foreign_reference OPTIONS (user fdwuser, password        
   'secret');  
   CREATE USER MAPPING FOR bon SERVER foreign_profile OPTIONS (user fdwuser, password 
   'secret'); 
   CREATE USER MAPPING FOR jhon SERVER foreign_reference OPTIONS (user fdwuser, password        
   'secret');  
   CREATE USER MAPPING FOR bon SERVER foreign_profile OPTIONS (user fdwuser, password 
   'secret');  
   CREATE USER MAPPING FOR jhon SERVER foreign_reference OPTIONS (user fdwuser, password 
   'secret');  
   CREATE USER MAPPING FOR bon SERVER foreign_profile OPTIONS (user referensi, password 
   'secret');
   ```
5. Import the foreign schemas into database A1, A2, A3:

   ```
   IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public FROM SERVER foreign_profile INTO profile;  
   IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public FROM SERVER foreign_referencd INTO reference;
   ```

The whole process is a success. **I can access the foreign table on Server B from Server A**. Fine, no problem.

Now, I check the WAL files using `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_ls_dir('pg_wal') WHERE pg_ls_dir ~ '^[0-9A-F]{24}';`. **It shows some 2100+ files**. This is worrying.

Here is the setting on server A:

```
archive_command cd .
archive_mode    on
checkpoint_completion_target    0.9
checkpoint_flush_after  32
checkpoint_timeout  300
wal_level   replica
wal_keep_segments   8
max_wal_senders 10
max_wal_size    8192
hot_standby on
```

Then I do some checking:

1. `select * from pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity`

   There are 250 entries, dominated by `backend_type` = `parallel worker` or `client backend`
2. `select * from pg_catalog.pg_stat_archiver`

   ```
   Failed_count = 0;
   Archived_count = 71;
   ```
3. After a copule of minutes, then I run `select * from pg_catalog.pg_stat_archiver` again. It now says :

   ```
   Failed_count = 0;
   Archived_count = 3; -- it seems to be reset for some reasons
   ```
4. Check the replication :
   `select * from pg_catalog.pg_stat_replication`. Results :

   `state = streaming`

   `sync_state = async`

This server seems to be busy I think.

Questions:

1. Why WALs keep on increasing? Is this normal? If not, should I reduce them?
2. Why is the `archived_count` reset?
3. What does this command do: `archive_command  cd .`?

Comment: Why did you turn on archive mode? And why did you turn it on without configuring a proper archive command?

Comment: not sure why turning the archive mode without the proper archive command. I guess the other DBA does not want to reset the server. From what I read, turning the `archive_command = cd .` is a hacky workaround :[https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77626/when-do-i-have-to-use-archive-command-and-when-not]. I do not know the reason, but the server has been working well. Seems like all the archived WALs vanish into thin air. The only thing that is unwell is the number of WALs

Comment: Nevertheless, that has nothing to do with your FDWs they don't change who much WAL is generated or kept (as e.g. logical replication)

Comment: yes @a_horse_with_no_name . you are right. I just checked, there is `streaming replication` going on as well alongside FDW. so definitely the replication has something to do with the WALs.

Comment: Probably a stale replication slot. Look into `pg_replication_slots` for entries where `active` is false. Drop those replication slots and wait for the next checkpoint.

Comment: yes @LaurenzAlbe , there is `physical replication` going on. I check `pg_replication_slots : slot_type = physical, active YES, slot_name = pgstandby1` But physical replication does not require WALs right ?

Comment: It does. What do you get for `SELECT pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), sent_lsn) FROM pg_stat_replication;`? Perhaps the standby has fallen behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing foreign schemas needs to generate WAL, as it needs to enter the descriptions of those tables into the system catalogs.  But it should not generate huge amounts of WAL, unless those foreign schemas have a huge number of tables (is is the number of tables and columns that matter, not the number of rows in the tables.  Because only the description of the tables gets recorded, not the contents).

So most likely, FDW has nothing to do with this.  It is something else which is generating that WAL, and something else again (probably replication slots) which is causing the WAL to be retained.

You can run `pg_waldump` on the retained WAL to try to figure out what is causing so much of it.  This is not easy to interpret, so it would probably be best to just think about what your system is doing other than FDW to come up with theories first.

Comment: How about the `archive_count` that reset? What caused it to reset? On another server, the counter keeps on going.